# attributed string which can accept instances depending upon what is passed from a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4, nsattributedstring

I have a tableView which users will select an instance. I have segue set-up to pass the instance to the textView. I have an NSLog setup so I know the correct data is being passed.  I want to setup an NSAttributedString to accept the data and import the relevant portions into the attributedString template.

Seems to me it should look like this:

```
displayText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"%@\n%@-%@",detailName, beginDate, endDate") attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26]}];
```

My ideal formatting is would be to create the string and have identify the name, begin, and end spaces in a way that allows them to have individual attributes. I've tried every combination of moving pieces but I simply cannot make this work. I receive errors such as Incompatible pointer types sending NSString to NSAttributedString, too many arguments, etc.

I'm new to programming and learning as I go but I've bought books and watched videos but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.  Thanks for the help.

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to use NSString's stringWithFormat: in order to pass variables to the string. Here's an example: (and there was an extraneous quotation mark after the argument list)

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26]};

NSMutableAttributedString *displayText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@-%@",detailName, beginDate, endDate] attributes:attributes];
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it must be simple but I cannot thank you enough. Is there a way for me to say detailName receives it's own formatting and begin date receives different formatting?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It will entail determining the ranges of the substrings within the overall string and applying specific formatting to that range using `[anAttributtedString addAttribute:<#(NSString *)#> value:<#(id)#> range:<#(NSRange)#>];`

Comment: One more question, can you tell me how to embed an image into this attributedString? Everything I've read indicates I have to do this in CoreText directly.  I've looked for appendWithImage and the like but can't find anything.  Thank you

Comment: @Isaac Your research is correct. This had to be done in Core Text until iOS 7. Here is a link to the WWDC 13 sample code download page. Check out the file titled "iOS_introToTextKit"   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. I'm not supporting iOS7 yet (that's another debate as to when to support that).  At least I'm not missing anything.  Thanks again for your help.